# GET endpoint returns a 404

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I am trying to retrieve specific user data from my Postgres DB.

This code, which retrievs all user data works:

```
app.get("/employees", async (req, res) => {
  try {   
    const allEmployees = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM employees");
    res.json(allEmployees.rows);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

But this code meant to retrieve one user doesn't. It returns a 404 on Postman.

```
app.get("/employees/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const oneEmployee = await pool.query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_id = $1", [
      id
    ]);

    res.json(oneEmployee.rows[0]);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
  }
});
```

I don't seem to figure out what the problem is.

Comment: can you post a sample postman request? also, are you logging anything on the server? it seems you aren't according to the code. Also, it seems you are not responding in the error cases.

Comment: console.log(id) is what you are looking for as the next step in debugging.

Comment: @AnujPancholi ``` http://localhost:3000/employees/emp_id=4``` that's the GET endpoint on postman. It returns an empty object ```[] ``` now after I left the params options without any values

Answer (score 0):

@AnujPancholi an update. I used the node-postgres queries documentation and changed my code as follows:

```
app.get("/employees/:emp_id", async (req,res) => {
 const query = {
   // give the query a unique name
   name: 'fetch-user',
   text: 'SELECT * FROM employees WHERE emp_id = $1'    
 }

 query.values = [req.params.emp_id];

 // callback
 await pool.query(query, (err, response) => {
   if (err) {
     console.log(err.stack);
   } else {
     res.json(response.rows);
   }
 });
});
```

then on Postman my endpoint to a GET route

```
http://localhost:3000/employees/4
```

I did not enter any values on the params section. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, especially on the Postman part.